# installing PlayFramework 2.4 on Ubuntu Webserver via ssh in Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, installation, playframework-2.4

I'm using Play 2.4 local for a while.

I would like to install a project now on an Ubuntu Webserver at my University for testing purposes. Unfortunately I'm a total noob with installing Play via Bash and start an existing Project.

I just googled that, but I can't find a useful How-to for installing Play 2.4 and running an existing Project via Bash.

Hope you can help me up

Greetings from Cologne

Chris

Comment: I'd just buid a distribution with `activator dist` and then run your app with `target/universal/stage/bin/my-first-app` like it's described in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production.

Comment: Hey Kris,
the Activator doesn't run instantly on Ubuntu.
I already fixed it on my own. I just installed sbt and it worked fine for me. Unfortunately this is no where documentated. Maybe it was back in older version, but isn't anymore. 

Thanks anyway:)
Chris